# Reproducing simple t-test result with ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, t-test

We know that a t-test is just a special case of ANOVA, so I tried to reproduce the result of the following t-test with `aov()` or `anova(lm())`

```
A <- c(56,65,69,78,72,82,81,87,89,81)
B <- c(78,88,89,91,84,87,92,94,92,90)

t.test(A,B,var.equal=TRUE)
```

I get different p-values, no matter what parameter combinations I try - please help!

Comment: The sample variance of A is 107.3, and the sample variance of B is 21.8. Why are you assuming that the variances are equal?

Comment: @Alexis: There is no special reason, I am only trying to reproduce the results of a paper with R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the problem. For me

```
t.test(A,B,var.equal=TRUE)
```

and

```
summary(aov(c(A,B)~rep(c("A","B"),each=10)))
```

and

```
anova(lm(c(A,B)~rep(c("A","B"),each=10)))
```

all result in $p=0.00268$.